# How to get the Traditional Buddhist Lunisolar calendar on Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: gnome, configuration, system-settings, calendar, internationalization

I am wondering if there is anyway to easily change between calendars, or change between them at all?

Specifically what I'm looking for is to be able to change my calendar to the Traditional Buddhist Lunisolar calendar (including month names etc as well as the year), and then to be able to easily change it back to the default if necessary.

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   vivid
Flavour: Gnome
Gnome Version: 3.18
```

Comment: This possible for at least the Islamic calendar, using this package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/hijra-applet. Other, related options include: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/chinese-calendar, http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/hdate-applet, http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/jcal, http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/hebcal